# cakephp plugin for live chat integration on website

Tags: cakephp-1.3, livechat

Any free but good chat plugin available which can be integrated with cakephp based portal?

Comment: Hi, Any thing you found regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Jaxl IM](http://jaxl.im) which doesn't require any software/hardware pre-requisites from your site servers. Just embed piece of available javascript code and you have your chat bar up and working.